# Send Push notification for specific users in MFP console

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, worklight-server

I have thousand users for both apple, android and I need to send the Push notification for all users at a time - based on the Email IDs. How to add all Emails at a time in the User ID field in image (I tired with comma separated and Semi colon separated, but it is taking as a single user.) kindly provide if there is any alternate option.
[Image - Push Notification from MFP console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH43a.jpg)

Comment: It says "add a User", so it seems, you can only add one user at a time.

Comment: Geshode, Kindly provide if any alternate possibility is there

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the email ids by putting space between two email ids in User ID column.
[image]

Comment: Man, email Ids just separated with space and it works as expected. Thank you very much bro. You saved my time.

Comment: Arun, Can you tell me how many emails can we add and what is the maximum limit.

Comment: i will do in batches of 1000 so that the portal does not become unresponsive. You can try more if your hardware permits.

Comment: @raghavendrarao Why you are not trying using REST API. Its very difficult to add 1000 mail id manually in console.

Comment: @Gaurab, I tried REST API by giving "userIds" : [ "myemail@gmail.com"], the response is always "Internal server error. No devices found." with "code": "FPWSE0009E"

Answer (score 0):

From the MFP Operations console, you can only send notification to a single userid at a time. There are two options:

1. Send notification one after the other - to different ids.
2. Use the REST API to send to multiple users in one go. The details of the REST call is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_message_post.html).

With the REST call, you can pass on a  list of userids in an array like so:

```
"target" : {
    "userIds" : [ "MyUserId1", "MyUserId2",... ]
  }...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried giving the email IDs in the User IDs array which are registered with the app. But I am getting No devices found error. Kindly help me.

Comment: Please tell me what exactly I have to pass in the userIds array.

Comment: If the emailids are not working, then you have not registered or subscribed with the email as the useridentity. You need to do this first , so that you can send notification against email.

Comment: This REST call :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_device_subscriptions_get.html
will tell you the useridentity against your subscriptions.